# Can I play on my PS4 while my girlfriend plays on PS Vita?

Tags: ps4, ps-vita

This may be a dumb question but I have a PS4 with a PS Plus account. I want to purchase a PS Vita for my girlfriend to play on. If I add my PS plus account to the Vita will she be able to play games on it while I'm playing on the PS4?
E.g. while I'm playing Fifa she can play Little Big planet on the Vita.

Comment: The tricky part about this question is actually having a girlfriend <badum-tshhh>

Comment: @Lohoris. That's not tricky at all. You just need to raise her affection and all the necessary flags, and if it gets too tough, you can always use console commands to- wait, you didn't mean *in real-life*, did you?

Comment: hahahah *forever alone meme*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes- but she can't play any PS4 games through remote play while you're playing one. If she's playing a downloaded or physical Vita game, there should be no conflict issues.

I've actually tried this with the PS4 and Vita before, as I have my PS+ account on both systems, as well as my PS3.

Comment: I can confirm you can play on both, but messages from friends and game invites directed to the account can get a bit screwed up. Sometimes they show up on both devices, sometimes on just one, it seems the system allows two devices to play on one account simultaneously but it does nothing extra to support it.

Answer (score 0):

If you connect the vita to ps4 can you play against each other one on one device one on the other

Comment: Elaborate 'connect'. Also, are there any required pre-requisites (ie. two accounts with each having a copy of any game(s) that you want to play together?)